# String Array property in COM Class and set it from VBA

Tags: c#, vba, com, marshalling, tlb

I am recently working with one type library requirement. I have created a c# class that will be exposed to COM component. However, when I set a value to an array property I get a compiler error. All the code are placed here.

Looking forward to your expert comments!

> **(VBA) Compile error:**
>    *Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic*

**C# Com Class**

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(_LeafletTestClass))]
[ProgId("Leaflet.WebService.Toolkit.LeafletWS.LeafletTestClass")]
[Guid("364C5E66-4412-48E3-8BD8-7B2BF09E8922")]
public class LeafletTestClass : _LeafletTestClass
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public string[] TestArrayString
    {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)]
        get;
        [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)]
        set;
    }

}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("8C034F6A-1D3F-4DB8-BC99-B73873D8C297")]
public interface _LeafletTestClass
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    string[] TestArrayString
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

**VBA Create Object**

```vb
Sub test()

Dim testClass As LeafletTestClass
Set testClass = New LeafletTestClass
Dim arr(0 To 1) As String
arr(0) = "Test value"
testClass.TestArrayString = arr

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a compiler error.

Comment: Sorry I completely missed it in your post, it looked like a code block

Comment: Why are you using `ClassInterfaceType.None`? Any particular reason?

Comment: You want `ClassInterfaceType.None` to ensure the COM interop doesn't get cute and give you a duplicate interface for which you have already defined yourself.

Comment: If I am using, reg free COM, which I prefer, you don't even need to worry about stale COM interfaces. But what you said above is true since eternity.  Just not the practical way to do things.

Comment: Reg free COM or not, it's still good principle to ensure that you are not generating junk metadata. Yes, it's nice that COM interop helps you out, but it can only help *naively*; taking control ensures that it won't suddenly behave in a weird way when your implementation changes and thus trip up the assumptions the COM interop makes about your COM interfaces.

Comment: I am new to this type of declaration.  I have no clue what ClassInterfaceType.None  does. I got this code from the internet.  I have tried removing the statement and no luck.

Comment: @NitheenRao I would encourage you to get reading on COM and COM Interop first and try to understand the architecture. If you don't understand what it is doing, you will be very frustrated because much of COM is based on conventions not enforced by programming language itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185159/how-to-pass-byte-arrays-as-udt-properties-from-vb6-vba-to-c-sharp-com-dll

Comment: I see no obvious problem that could explain this runtime error.  Using the [Guid] attribute is pretty risky, it is a good way to cause very hard to diagnose DLL Hell.  In other words, your VBA code might be using an old version of the code that *does* have a bug.  Happens when you forget to re-register the new assembly.  The registry keys are still present, so the New LeafletTestClass statement *seems* to work just fine, but then keels over on the old interface definition.

Comment: Oh wait, there *is* a quirk in the VBA runtime.  You may need to use the Set keyword, not sure.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that you avoid using arrays. While you can use `Marshal` and possibly marshal it across it is fraught with issues due to difference in how empty arrays and nulls are handled, etc. etc.

To avoid runtime errors, you are better off writing a collection class and marshaling that across so that VBA can then simply enumerate. For an example of this, [see here](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/blob/next/Rubberduck.API/VBA/Declarations.cs)

At minimum your collection interface need to look like this:

```
[
    ComVisible(true),
    Guid(<some guid>),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)
]
public interface IDeclarations : IEnumerable
{
    [DispId(0)]
    Declaration Item(int Index);

    [DispId(1)]
    int Count { get; }

    [DispId(-4)]
    IEnumerator _GetEnumerator();
 }
```

Comment: I am still not getting how to replace this with Array.

Comment: Can you elaborate more -- what have you tried and what isn't working?