# Passing Type Arrays from VB6/VBA to C# COM DLL?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, com, .net-4.8

I have developed a C# library that contains different mathematical functions. It's been steadily growing with new functions at every release. A few of those functions take arrays of different types (double, integer) as parameters.

While developing a new function taking an Integer Array as a parameter I suddenly started getting a specific error in VBA.

***Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic***

I've been fighting this for two days now and I have found a solution. But I can't understand why it has suddenly changed.

This is a mockup of the C# code which gives exactly the same error

```c#
namespace ClassLibrary1
    {
        [Guid("77C507CE-E6D8-4780-B7E6-46526271CD05")]
        [ComVisible(true)]
        [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
        public class Class1 : IClass1
        {
            public double SumVector(double[] arr)
            {
                double sum = 0;
                foreach(var d in arr)
                {
                    sum += d;
                }
                return sum;
            }
        }
    
     [Guid("2E09C500-0C87-4EBF-A196-3D0E6770E55D")]
        [ComVisible(true)]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
        public interface IClass1
        {
            [DispId(1)]
            double SumVector(double[] arr);
        }
    }
```

This is a mockup of what the VBA code looks like that's using the exposed COM objects:

```vb6
Sub Test()
    
    Dim obj As ClassLibrary1.Class1
    Set obj = New ClassLibrary1.Class1
    
    Dim vect(0 To 4) As Double
    vect(0) = 1#
    vect(1) = 6#
    vect(2) = 5#
    vect(3) = 2#
    vect(4) = 3#
    
    Dim res As Double
    
    res = obj.SumVector(vect)

End Sub
```

There are two solutions.

1. Add the keyword '**ref**' to all uses of type Arrays as parameters in the C# code. Like this:

```c#
[DispId(1)]
double SumVector(ref double[] arr);
```

2. Use late binding in VBA of the class. While developing and testing new functions I tend to use early-binding. Switching to late-binding as is used in the released VBA client also solves the problem. Like this:

```VBA
Dim obj As Object
Set obj = CreateObject("ClassLibrary1.Class1")
```

The question is, has the requirement of how type arrays are to be passed from VBA/VB6 to C# (COM interop) changed in recent years?

Many of the functions taking type arrays has been ported from a legacy C++ library. As I can see, it's the same way there:

```C++
STDMETHODIMP Class1::SumVector(SAFEARRAY *psaXvector, double *sum)
{
    ...
}
```

```IDL
[id(1), helpstring("method SumVector"),helpcontext(1)]
            HRESULT SumVector(
                [in] SAFEARRAY(double) Xvector
                [out,retval] double *Sum);
```

You can find the mockup library on my [Github page](https://github.com/jahlqvis/ClassLibrary1)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/array-argument-must-be-byref

Comment: @HansPassant Passant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-arrays According to this doc, marshalling int or double safearrays doesn't require ref. But the VBA requires all Dim, ReDim arrays to be passed ByRef. So that's why the 'ref' keyword is needed?

Comment: Yes.  It is a simple VBA rule to ensure that it does not have to generate inefficient code.  Passing byval would require it to make a copy of the array so that the callee cannot modify the array content.  Especially painful for large arrays of course.  It is not fundamentally different in .NET, arrays are always reference types and there is no way to intentionally make a copy.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. Found this answer as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13185863/8119788